# Open url in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that when users open my web site  a new window or tab will be open after 10 sec, I found this function window.open("yoururl") but it seems that it only work on click event so how can I make it work without a click event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout('openUrl()',10000);

})

function openUrl() {
 window.open("yoururl");
}
```

Comment: That's by design. Non user initiated popups are evil.

Comment: did you try `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: Popup-Blockers will prevent this action. Popups and windows opening on their own are highly annoying to the User and they will bring you no advantage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **not permitted** to open new window by using any event that is not triggered by **user action**. Some sites trick the users in clicking something else and then making use of that action to do popup. But it is unacceptable and truly annoying user experience.